# How to write simple function which will return rows based on column with date in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

| ID | DATE | LOG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-12-31 | 2021-12-30 |
| 445 | 2021-12-31 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2232 | 2021-12-31 | NaN |

And I need to create function which argument will be date from column "DATE" and this function will return ID of clients from column "ID" who were logged (column "LOG") before date from column "DATE" or have NaN in column "LOG". So fo example:

```
my_function(df["DATE"])
```

will return because these clients who have LOG < DATE or LOG == NaN

```
ID
-----
123
2232
```

Comment: try this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ways-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-by-column-values/

Answer (score 2):

You could write your condition and use boolean indexing:

```
def my_function(df):
    msk = (df['DATE'] > df['LOG']) | df['LOG'].isna()
    return df.loc[msk, 'ID']

>>> my_function(df)
0     123
2    2232
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This function takes *two* arguments to print your clients `ID` where `LOG` is not **NaN**
and have logged before date time value from `"DATE"`

```py
import numpy as np

def my_function(df, date):
    return df["ID"].loc((not np.isnan(df["LOG"])) | (df["DATE"]>df["LOG"]))
```